# Adding anchor points at a specific measurement on a curved

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pen-tool

I have a curved path with two anchor points currently.  I want to add an anchor point 1.5" from one anchor point. I am not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

- Open Menu Edit->Preferences->Units, set 'General and 'Stroke' to Inches.
- Select your curve, open Appearance Panel (Shift-F6) and click Stroke, select 'Dashed Line' and set first dash length=1,5in, use this dash as a visual marker to set additional point (with the help of pen tool)